# How do I construct pandas DataFrame from nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, dictionary

Here is my dict:

```
{'ItemA': {'margin': 0.52, 'Factory': 'CA', 'Qty': '50'}, 
 'ItemB': {'ItemB1': {'margin': 0.4, 'Factory': 'CHI', 'Qty': '80'}, 
           'ItemB2': {'margin': 0.1,'Factory': 'CHI', 'Qty': '60'}}}
```

How do I convert this dictionary to a data frame like this?

| Item | Item member | Margin | Factory | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ItemA | None | 0.52 | CA | 50 |
| ItemB | ItemB1 | 0.4 | CHI | 80 |
| ItemB | ItemB2 | 0.1 | CHI | 60 |

Comment: try [DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: DataFrame.from_dict is not work for this case.

Comment: can you redesign your dictionary ?

Comment: How was the dict created in the first place?

Comment: ItemB1 and ItemB2 are 2 parts of ItemB, that is why this dict looks like this...

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74227707/15810641 if answer you question or not !

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ItemA': {'margin': 0.52, 'Factory': 'CA', 'Qty': '50'},
        'ItemB': {'ItemB1': {'margin': 0.4, 'Factory': 'CHI', 'Qty': '80'},
                  'ItemB2': {'margin': 0.1, 'Factory': 'CHI', 'Qty': '60'}}}

new_dict = {
    'Item': [],
    'Item member': [],
    'Margin': [],
    'Factory': [],
    'Qty': []
}

item_lock = False
for item in data:
    new_dict['Item'].append(item)
    for item_number in data[item]:
        if isinstance(data[item][item_number], str | int | float):
            if len(new_dict['Item']) != len(new_dict['Item member']):
                new_dict['Item member'].append(None)
            new_dict[item_number.title()].append(data[item][item_number])
        elif isinstance(data[item][item_number], dict):
            new_dict['Item member'].append(item_number)

            if len(new_dict['Item']) != len(new_dict['Item member']):
                new_dict['Item'].append(item)

            for other in data[item][item_number]:
                new_dict[other.title()].append(data[item][item_number][other])

df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
df.set_index('Item', inplace=True)
print(df)
```